# As3 Creating a tiled background

Tags: actionscript, background, png, tile

First of all, I would like to say that I'm fairly new to AS3, so feel free to correct me when needed.

So I'm trying to create a moving background, made out of different types of isometric tiles, like a floor or a wall, disposen in a grid like fashion.

At first, I tried creating a symbol containing the floor and the wall on different frames, and alternate between the frames as needed. Then I would add multiple instances of this symbol to a container and move the container around. Quickly I realized that this probably wouldn't be an ifficient method, as confirmed by the unsmooth movement of the container. (I gave up on this method).

So I did a little digging around, and then I converted the tile symbol to a png file, created a bitmap container to where I would copyPixels from the png as many times as the map required it.

The problem now is that when I do this:

```
var pngBitmapData:BitmapData=new tilePng
```

the bitmapData height and width don't match the height and width of the actual tile. There seem to be some transparent pixels around the tile and I have no idea how to remove them. This causes the tiles to be misaligned on the background's grid, with some small empty spaces around them.

So I have a couple of questions:

1. Is this an effective way to build the background?
2. Is there a way to avoid that transparent pixels "problem" ?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, it's hard to tell without seeing your png.

Are you doing this?

```
var pngBitmapData:BitmapData = new tilePng();
var bmp:Bitmap = new Bitmap(pngBitmapData);
```

To initialize your bitmap?

Also, check the anti-aliasing on your bitmap, that could be it. I'd set it to none.